# Find the distribution function and the density function of random variable $Y=X_1+X_2$ without using convolution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Working on a problem on probability and I just cannot get myself to make any progress.

Supposed that the 2-dimensional random vector $X=(X_1, X_2)$ has joint p.d.f $f(x_1,x_2)$, i.e. $f$ is a non-negative Borel function s.t. $\int fdy=1$, and for any $x \in \mathbb R^2$, $$P(X\leq x)=\int 1_{(-\infty ,x]}(y)f(y)dy$$ where $1_{(-\infty ,x]}(y)$ is the indicator function. Here $dy$ denotes the integration w.r.t $m_2$, the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2]^2$, $$f(x)=\frac{1}{4} 1_{[0,2]}(x_1)1_{[0,2]}(x_2)$$ Find the distribution function and probability density function of $Y=X_1+X_2$.

For this question, if I know the distribution function of $X=(X_1,X_2)$, how can I split up the function coordinate wise? Ultimately, are the d.f. and p.d.f. of $Y=X_1+X_2$ simply the sum of the distribution functions and the density functions?

I've been stuck on these problems for a very long time, and I cannot make any progress. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the theorem that says something about uniqueness of measure?

Comment: Which theorem are you referring to? The one that states for a distribution function $F$, there is a unique probability $Q_F$?

Comment: No the one that says something about two measures agreeing on a collection of sets (that satisfy some properties).

Comment: If two measures agree on set $C$, and $C$ is a $\pi$-system, then the measures agree on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C$?

Comment: Yes! Okay let me tell you how to use it. Define $$\nu(A) =\int_A f(y) dy$$ and verify that this is a probability measure. You have another probability measure, namely the law of $X$... You know how to proceed now?

Comment: So show that the defined measure is a probability on $(\mathbb R^2, \mathcal B(\mathbb R^2))$, and show the measure above, and the law agree on $\{(-\infty ,x]:x \in \mathbb R^2\}$?

Comment: $\int_Af(y)dy=\int 1_A(y)f(y)dy$ right? How can I explicitly show that?

Comment: Yes! That is the idea. For your last question look here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1526010/349501

Comment: @Shashi $1_{\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{A_n}$ right? Would I need to prove this explicitly? Also, any idea on how to do part 2?

Comment: @pilotmath Yes that is correct. If you're looking for the explicit proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297748/characteristic-function-of-a-disjoint-union

Comment: @user282639 yes, I managed to prove that already, but thanks anyways! Any idea on how to do the problem in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given "$X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2]^2$", so joint PDF is
$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{4}$$
inside $[0,2]^2$, zero outside.
Now,
$$f_{X_1}(x_1)=\int f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) dx_2=\int_0^2 \frac{1}{4} dx_2=\frac{1}{2}$$
inside $[0,2]$, zero outside. The same is true for $f_{X_2}(x_2)$.

Now we see that
$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)$$
so $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, and the PDF of $Y=X_1+X_2$ is convolution of $f_{X_1}(x_1)$ and $f_{X_2}(x_2)$.

Comment: How did you obtain $f_X(x_1)=\int f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)dx_2$? Also is the distribution function of Y then the sum of the two distribution function?

Comment: @pilotmath 1) by definition of marginal PDF; 2) No, it is convolution.

Comment: The PDF of $Y$ is the convolution of the two functions, right? What would be the distribution function of $Y$ then?

Comment: @pilotmath convolution of two rectangle functions is easiest convolution to calculate, just do it. Hint: the resulting convolution is triangle function.

Comment: I had no problem finding the PDF by using convolution, but I'm not sure how to get the distribution function of $Y$.